# Special characters in web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, iis-7, web-config

I've create a custom configuration section in my web.config file for my 3.5 web application. The custom configuration contains special characters listed below.

```
  <add Key="2" String="â€"/>
  <add Key="3" String="148"/>
  <add Key="4" String="!X"/>
  <add Key="5" String="¡§"/>
  <add Key="6" String="¡¦"/>
  <add Key="7" String="¡¨"/>
  <add Key="8" String="’" />
  <add Key="9" String="–" />
```

I currently have the xml type of the web.config defined as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

This works fine in one development environment, but when I migrate the application to another environment I get an xml parsing error on the string for Key 2. When I replace all the string definitions for each config entry with standard alpha chars, the application works fine. Is there a way to enforce the XML to be read the same way? I have looked into the encoding attribute for the xml definition tag, just not positive what to set it to. Any guidance would be well appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you typing these into your web.config file manually? Can't you just HTML-encode your string values?

Comment: It's XML, not HTML. Numeric entity codes would work, but not other HTML entities.

Comment: No, I did't type those values in manually. I used the HTML-encode  solution to fix my issue and it worked out well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend setting the encoding to "utf-8". Make sure the file is also actually saved as utf-8.

Comment: Tried this and still no luck. Ended up going with Jonathan solution so I didn't have to rely on the encoding type.